# How to reshape a pandas dataframe based on column values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to reshape my data based on column values and then transpose the dataframe so that groups of column values become column headings. For example I'd like to go from:

```
# Creating an illustrative dataframe:

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

categories = np.repeat(list('abc'), 3)
data = np.arange(len(categories))
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': data, 'Data2': data*2, 'Category': categories})

   Data  Data2 Category
0     0      0        a
1     1      2        a
2     2      4        a
3     3      6        b
4     4      8        b
5     5     10        b
6     6     12        c
7     7     14        c
8     8     16        c
```

to look like:

```
   a  b  c
0  0  3  6
1  1  4  7
2  2  5  8
```

I've tried an approach using `pd.DataFrame.pivot()`:

```
[In]
df.pivot(columns='Category', values='Data')

[Out]
Category    a    b    c
0         0.0  NaN  NaN
1         1.0  NaN  NaN
2         2.0  NaN  NaN
3         NaN  3.0  NaN
4         NaN  4.0  NaN
5         NaN  5.0  NaN
6         NaN  NaN  6.0
7         NaN  NaN  7.0
8         NaN  NaN  8.0
```

Is there a way to 'ignore' the index when using `pd.DataFrame.pivot()` or is there an alternative approach to producing the desired output?

Comment: Specifically, see question 10 in the duplicate. First create the `index` with `groupby` + `cumcount` then you pivot.

Comment: You'll need to help `pivot_table` with the index, `df.pivot_table(index = df.groupby('Category').cumcount(), columns='Category', values='Data')`